# React hooks functions have old version of a state var

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I tried to make a nice animating example for myself using Hooks but I have stumbled upon a problem where my functions won't have the updated version of a state var and continue to use the first version.

In the snippet below I have an example where once you click on a bar it's supposed to move in a square formation. First going east, then south, then west, then north and then east again etc. However it never goes south because even though its direction is updated from `north` to `east` (indicated by the text on the bar or clicking on it again), the functions still think that the direction is north.

```js
const Example = (props) => {
  const [ direction, setDirection ] = React.useState('North');
  console.log("Rendering Example: ", direction);
  
  const isAnimating = React.useRef(false)
  const blockRef = React.useRef(null);
  
  // Animate on click.
  const onClick = () => {
    if (!isAnimating.current) {
      decideDirection();
      isAnimating.current = true
    } else {
      console.log("Already animating. Going: ", direction);
    }
  };
  
  const decideDirection = () => {
    console.log("Current direction: ", direction);
    if (direction === 'North') {
      moveEast();
    } else if (direction === 'East') {
      moveSouth();
    } else if (direction === 'South') {
      moveWest();
    } else if (direction === 'West') {
      moveNorth();
    }
  };
  
  const move = (toX, toY, duration, onComplete) => {
    Velocity(blockRef.current, {
      translateX: toX,
      translateY: toY,
      complete: () => {
        onComplete();
      }
    },
    {
      duration: duration
    });
  }
  
  const moveNorth = () => {
    setDirection('North');
    console.log('Moving N: ', direction);
    move(0, 0, 500, () => {
      decideDirection();
    })
  }
  
  const moveEast = () => {
    setDirection('East');
    console.log('Moving E: ', direction);
    move(500, 0, 2500, () => {
      decideDirection();
    })
  };
  
  const moveSouth = () => {
    setDirection('South');
    console.log('Moving S: ', direction);
    move(500, 18, 500, () => {
      decideDirection();
    })
  }
  
  const moveWest = () => {
    setDirection('West');
    console.log('Moving W: ', direction);
    move(0, 18, 2500, () => {
      decideDirection();
    })
  }
  
  return(
    <div>
      <div id='block' onClick={onClick} ref={blockRef} style={{ width: '100px', height: '18px', backgroundColor: 'red', textAlign: 'center'}}>{direction}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<div><Example/></div>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.2/velocity.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='root' style='width: 100%; height: 100%'>
</div>
```

I find this kind of strange because none of these functions are memoized so they should re-create every render and thus have the new value. Even if I do add something like `useCallback` and provide `direction` to every function it still won't work. Why don't the functions know about the updated version of the state var?

Comment: I think this article can help you clarify https://overreacted.io/how-are-function-components-different-from-classes/ The state on the functions when you don't use classes is different,

Comment: Thank you for the article this explains a lot! Although I disagree with the writer that classes are the wrongdoer here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that your `move` functions have closed over the initial version of `decideDirection`. Your div has re-rendered, but the animation continues with references to the initial versions of the functions. One way to resolve this is to use a ref to point at the `decideDirection` function (I've shown this approach in the snippet below).

This seems a little brittle though since the timing of the re-render vs. the timing of the animation makes it difficult to reason as to whether this is robust. A more robust approach would involve chaining the moves more explicitly via state changes such that rather than directly calling `decideDirection` at completion of each animation, you instead set state that will trigger an effect to start the next animation.

```js
const Example = (props) => {
  const [ direction, setDirection ] = React.useState('North');
  console.log("Rendering Example: ", direction);
  
  const isAnimating = React.useRef(false)
  const blockRef = React.useRef(null);
  const decideDirection = () => {
    console.log("Current direction: ", direction);
    if (direction === 'North') {
      moveEast();
    } else if (direction === 'East') {
      moveSouth();
    } else if (direction === 'South') {
      moveWest();
    } else if (direction === 'West') {
      moveNorth();
    }
  };
  const decideDirectionRef = React.useRef(decideDirection);
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    decideDirectionRef.current = decideDirection;
  });
  
  // Animate on click.
  const onClick = () => {
    if (!isAnimating.current) {
      decideDirectionRef.current();
      isAnimating.current = true
    } else {
      console.log("Already animating. Going: ", direction);
    }
  };
  
  const move = (toX, toY, duration, onComplete) => {
    Velocity(blockRef.current, {
      translateX: toX,
      translateY: toY,
      complete: () => {
        onComplete();
      }
    },
    {
      duration: duration
    });
  }
  
  const moveNorth = () => {
    setDirection('North');
    console.log('Moving N: ', direction);
    move(0, 0, 500, () => {
      decideDirectionRef.current();
    })
  }
  
  const moveEast = () => {
    setDirection('East');
    console.log('Moving E: ', direction);
    move(500, 0, 2500, () => {
      decideDirectionRef.current();
    })
  };
  
  const moveSouth = () => {
    setDirection('South');
    console.log('Moving S: ', direction);
    move(500, 18, 500, () => {
      decideDirectionRef.current();
    })
  }
  
  const moveWest = () => {
    setDirection('West');
    console.log('Moving W: ', direction);
    move(0, 18, 2500, () => {
      decideDirectionRef.current();
    })
  }
  
  return(
    <div>
      <div id='block' onClick={onClick} ref={blockRef} style={{ width: '100px', height: '18px', backgroundColor: 'red', textAlign: 'center'}}>{direction}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<div><Example/></div>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.2/velocity.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='root' style='width: 100%; height: 100%'>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah I agree that there are a ton of better ways to write it, I was just really confused why this particular approach wasn't working. Thanks!

Comment: While not a bad answer, I think it would be much more succinct to simply say your function has a value capture bug as @ygweric says below.

Answer (score 0):

your value is **captured**, have a look about [my another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66326683/1142674)

Comment: Very helpful answer, but it could be more helpful if it included a code snippet of the specific issue.

Also, I'd move your answer to this page because I think that link is a duplicate of this page (already flagged it).