# Incorrect state upon hook callback

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I'm writing a chat client using socket.io and react hooks. The message history (chatMessages) when `addMessage` (upon receiving the message event) is called is incorrect (always an empty array). `chatMessages` does update (correctly), but on the next call it is empty. There shouldn't be any other variable named   `chatMessages` and messages is in the parent class (the set hook works so I don’t see why the state should be invalid). The state doesn't appear to update again either, so it appears to something in add messages.

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles/chat.css";
import { uuidv4 } from "./utils/utils";
const SERVER_URL = "http://localhost:3337";
const io = require("socket.io-client");


function ChatManager(props) {
  // How to handle sockets (where do we store them)
  const [UId, setUId] = useState("");
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);
  const [chatMessages, setChatMessages] = useState([]);
  const [role, setRole] = useState("Role");
  const useForceUpdate = () => useState()[1];
  function displayMessage(msg) {
    if (UId) {
      if (msg.user === UId) {
        return (
          <article class="msg-container msg-self" id="msg-0">
            <div class="msg-box">
              <div class="flr">
                <div class="messages">
                  <p class="msg" id="msg-0">
                    {msg.message}
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </article>
        );
      } else {
        return (
          <article class="msg-container msg-remote" id="msg-0">
            <div class="msg-box">
              <div class="flr">
                <div class="messages">
                  <p class="msg" id="msg-0">
                    {msg.message}
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </article>
        );
      }
    }
  }

  function addMessage(msg) {
    console.log("message: ");
    console.log(msg);
    const newMessages = [...chatMessages];
    console.log(chatMessages);
    newMessages.push(msg);
    console.log(newMessages);
    setChatMessages(newMessages);
    console.log("Message added");

  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("did mount");
    if (!socket) {
      setUId(uuidv4());
      console.log("Set UId");
      setSocket(io.connect(SERVER_URL));
      console.log("Socket mounted");
    } else {
      console.log("Socket emit");

      socket.emit("join", {
        uid: UId,
        tid: "Task ID, add later",
        role: role
      });

      socket.on("error", function(err) {
        console.log("received socket error:");
        console.log(err);
      });

      socket.on("message", function(msg) {
     addMessage(msg);
      });
    }
    return () => {
      console.log("Unmounting");
      if (socket) {
        socket.emit("leave", {
          uid: UId,
          tid: "Task ID, add later",
          role: role
        });
        console.log("Leaving message sent");
      }
    };
  }, [socket]);

  function sendMessage() {
    const msg = "Test message";
    socket.emit("usr_input", {
      uid: UId,
      tid: "Task ID, add later",
      message: msg,
      role: role
    });

    console.log("Message sent");
  }

return (
    <div>
      <h1> Here is the chatbox </h1>
      <ChatBox 
      sendMessage={sendMessage} 
      chatMessages={chatMessages}
      displayMessage={displayMessage}/>
      <h1> EOF </h1>
    </div>
  );
}

function ChatBox(props) {
  return (
    <section class="chatbox">
      <section id="chat-messages" class="chat-window">
        {props.chatMessages.map( (msg) => {props.displayMessage(msg)})}
      </section>

    <form class="chat-input" onsubmit="return false;">
        <input
          type="text"
          id="message"
          autocomplete="on"
          placeholder="Type a message"
        />
        <button type="button" onClick={props.sendMessage}>
          <svg
            style={{
              width: "24px",
              height: "24px"
            }}
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          >
            {" "}
            <path
              fill="rgba(0,0,0,.38)"
              d="M17,12L12,17V14H8V10H12V7L17,12M21,16.5C21,16.88 20.79,17.21 20.47,17.38L12.57,21.82C12.41,21.94 12.21,22 12,22C11.79,22 11.59,21.94 11.43,21.82L3.53,17.38C3.21,17.21 3,16.88 3,16.5V7.5C3,7.12 3.21,6.79 3.53,6.62L11.43,2.18C11.59,2.06 11.79,2 12,2C12.21,2 12.41,2.06 12.57,2.18L20.47,6.62C20.79,6.79 21,7.12 21,7.5V16.5M12,4.15L5,8.09V15.91L12,19.85L19,15.91V8.09L12,4.15Z"
            />{" "}
          </svg>{" "}
        </button>
      </form>
```

Any ideas or workarounds would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm running into the same issue and can't work out why. It's almost like a clojure issue but that doesn't make sense as the function in question is not memoized so should be updating itself.

Comment: @norbitrial's answer worked for my use case, I would recommend that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React hooks functions have old version of a state var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55066697/react-hooks-functions-have-old-version-of-a-state-var)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about if you mutate the previous state of your `chatMessages`?

As the `useState` hook [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)' documentation states:

> If the new state is computed using the previous state, you can pass a function to setState. The function will receive the previous value, and return an updated value.

Maybe you can try as the following code snippet:

```
function addMessage(msg) {
  setChatMessages(previousMessages => {
    return [
      ...previousMessages,
      msg
    ];
  });
}
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: It’s odd that it doesn’t  work without mutating the state, but I’ll look into it another time. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I guess your value is **capture**, have a look the following like for more detail.

Steps to fix it:

1. create a ref with `const myFuncRef = useRef(null)`
2. set ref.current to you function with `myFuncRef .current = myFunc`
3. call with func ref `onClick={val => myFuncRef .current(val)}`

[How to get the previous props or state?](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#can-i-run-an-effect-only-on-updates)

[How React Hooks Components Capture Values (And How To Use the Latest Values Instead)](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-how-react-hooks-components-capture-values-and-how-to-use-the-latest-values-instead)