# React & Typescript - custom hook to pull status updates resets back to initial status

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, state

**Situation**:
Im trying to write a custom hook that allows me to fetch data and launches a `setInterval` which polls status updates every two seconds. Once all data is processed, the interval is cleared to stop polling updates.

**Problem**:
My problem is that the function passed to `setInterval` only has the initial state (empty array) although it has already been updated. Either it is resetting back to the initial state or the function has an old reference.

**Code**:
Link to Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/pollingstate-9wziw7?file=/src/Hooks.tsx

Hook:

```js
export type Invoice = {id: number, status: string};

export async function executeRequest<T>(callback: () => T, afterRequest: (response: {error: string | null, data: T}) => void) {
  const response = callback();
  afterRequest({error: null, data: response});
}

export function useInvoiceProcessing(formData: Invoice[]): [result: Invoice[], executeRequest: () => Promise<void>] {

  const timer: MutableRefObject<NodeJS.Timer | undefined> = useRef();

  const [result, setResult] = useState<Invoice[]>(formData);

  // Mock what the API would return
  const firstRequestResult: Invoice[] = [
    {id: 1, status: "Success"},
    {id: 2, status: "Pending"}, // This one needs to be polled again
    {id: 3, status: "Failed"}
  ];
  const firstPoll: Invoice = {id: 2, status: "Pending"};
  const secondPoll: Invoice = {id: 2, status: "Success"};

  // The function that triggers when the user clicks on "Execute Request"
  async function handleFirstRequest() {
    await executeRequest(() => firstRequestResult, response => {
      if (!response.error) {
        setResult(response.data)
        if (response.data.some(invoice => invoice.status === "Pending")) {
          // Initialize the timer to poll every 2 seconds
          timer.current = setInterval(() => updateStatus(), 2000);
        }
      } else {
        // setError
      }
    })
  }

  let isFirstPoll = true; // Helper variable to simulate a first poll
  async function updateStatus() {
    // Result has the initial formData values (NotUploaded) but should already have the values from the first request
    console.log(result); 
    const newResult = [...result];
    let index = 0;
    for (const invoice of newResult) {
      if (invoice.status === "Pending") {
        await executeRequest(() => isFirstPoll ? firstPoll : secondPoll, response => {
          if (!response.error) {
            newResult[index] = response.data;
          } else {
            // Handle error
          }
        });
      }
      index++;
    }
  
    setResult(newResult);
    isFirstPoll = false;
    
    const areInvoicesPending = newResult.some(invoice => invoice.status === "Pending");
    if (!areInvoicesPending) {
      console.log("Manual clear")
      clearInterval(timer.current);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      console.log("Unmount clear")
      clearInterval(timer.current);
    }
  }, [])

  return [result, handleFirstRequest];
```

Usage:

```js
const [result, executeRequest] = useInvoiceProcessing([
    { id: 1, status: "NotUploaded" },
    { id: 2, status: "NotUploaded" },
    { id: 3, status: "NotUploaded" }
  ]);

  async function handleRequest() {
    console.log("Start request");
    executeRequest();
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleRequest}>Execute Request</button>
      <p>
        {result.map((invoice) => (
          <Fragment key={invoice.id}>
            {invoice.status}
            <br />
          </Fragment>
        ))}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
```

**EDIT1**
I have one possible solution. This post helped me in the right direction: [React hooks functions have old version of a state var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55066697/react-hooks-functions-have-old-version-of-a-state-var)

The closure that `updateStatus` uses is outdated. To solve that, I saved `updateStatus` in a `useRef` (`updateStatus` also needs `useCallback`). Although not necessary, I had to store `result` in a `useRef` as well but I'm not sure yet why.

```js
const updateStatusRef = useRef(updateStatus);
  useEffect(()=>{
    updateStatusRef.current = updateStatus;   
  }, [updateStatus]);
```

Here's a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/pollingstate-forked-njw4ct?file=/src/Hooks.tsx